# Install albumentations with custom opencv-python version using pip?

Tags: python, pip, albumentations

The [`albumentations` package](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) requires some version of `opencv-python`.  From [setup.py](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/setup.py):

```
# If none of packages in first installed, install second package
CHOOSE_INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    (
        ("opencv-python>=4.1.1", "opencv-contrib-python>=4.1.1", "opencv-contrib-python-headless>=4.1.1"),
        "opencv-python-headless>=4.1.1",
    )
]
```

When I `pip install`, it seems to choose `opencv-python-headless`, which has [a bug that prevents installation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/648).  (If you read the bug, it looks like I could install a different version of scikit-build, but that didn't seem to work.)

The workaround is to install a dev version of opencv-python, which I can with this line in requirements.txt:

```
git+https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python@5de8d66d454c8fd946ae17dcfcb285b16aa6049b
```

However, while installing `albumentations`, it decides to still install `opencv-python-headless`, presumably because the version number (installed from github) doesn't compare well.

How can I install `albumentations` and have it use my existing `opencv-python` install?

I installed `pip-tools`, and compiled the requirements for albumentation, and I've been messing with the file, but `pip` still follows dependencies for each package.

Can I use `pip` to install a package directly, without dependencies?  Then I could do it one at a time, with the versions I want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar problem what have done is:

1. Install opencv-python using pip install opencv-python==4.5.5
2. Download albumentations from github
3. git checkout {albumentations_version} you want to install
4. Change in albumentations/setup.py opencv-python>=4.1.1 with opencv-python==4.5.5.64
5. Update pip. pip install pip --upgrade. My version is 22.1.2
6. pip install albumentations/

At the end i have albumentations 1.1.0 installed with opencv-python==4.5.5 and not the latest version of opencv.